# How to implement sql between operator in zend_db

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following queries which calculates the total order sale happened in last 5 months,

```
>     SELECT SUM(o.total), DATE(o.order_date) dateonly FROM `order` as o where (o.order_date BETWEEN  last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND 
> date_format(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')  AND (o.order_status = "P" OR
> o.order_status = "T" OR o.order_status = "S" OR o.order_status = "D"
> )) GROUP BY month(o.order_date)
```

I am trying to implement above query in zend. But I stuck on middle.
I have the code taken from models/DbTable,

```
class Default_Model_DbTable_Order extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'order';
    protected $_primary = 'order_id';
    public function month_based_orderlist()
    {
        $oDb = Zend_Registry::get("db");        
        $whereSQL  = 'o.order_id > 0';
        $whereSQL .= ' AND o.status = 1';
        $whereSQL .= ' AND o.order_date BETWEEN  last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND  date_format(NOW(),'.%Y-%m-%d.')';
        $whereSQL .= ' AND o.order_status = "P"';
        $whereSQL .= ' OR o.order_status = "T"';
        $whereSQL .= ' OR o.order_status = "S"';
        $whereSQL .= ' OR o.order_status = "D"';
        $select = $oDb->select()
            ->from(
                array('o' => $this->_name), 
                array(
                    'lifetimesale' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(o.total)'),
                    'dateonly' => DATE('o.order_date')
                )
            )->where($whereSQL);

        //echo $select; exit;
        $result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
        // print_obj($result);
        return $result;            

    }
}
?>
```

I am trying to implement the sql query like above,what i done wrong on this.
 Kindly help me on this

Comment: You need to be more specific. How did you get 'stuck'? Can you post the error you received. Also, if you think this issue has to deal with zend, then post that code as well.

Comment: Could you, please, explain what problem do you mean? Do you use Zend_Db?

Comment: @Digital Precision  Updated my question now.

Comment: @Dinesh: Ok, now what is the specific problem? Are you not getting the results you expect, is it throwing a sql error, or is zend throwing an error?

Comment: @Digital Precision Thanks i fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is here:

```
.%Y-%m-%d.
```

**Edit**

Phil pointed out my solution was wrong. I rechecked and he was right. The solution should be just to remove the ticks, and put in double quotes:

```
// assume $date is set 
$whereSQL .= ' AND o.order_date BETWEEN last_day(NOW() -'
          . ' INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND date_format(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")';
```

Alternatively, you could escape the single quotes using the backslash and remove the sting concat operator:

```
... date_format(NOW(), \'%Y-%m-%d\')';
```

---

Also, I see you're extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and, as such, you don't need the line:

```
$oDb = Zend_Registry::get('db');
```

Just omit that and use `$this` instead. And it would look something like this (simplified with `GROUP BY` clause added):

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from($fromTable, $columns)
    ->where($whereSQL)
    ->group('month(o.order_date)');

$result = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

---

To add the `GROUP BY` clause, simply do this (or see above example using method chaining):

```
$select->group('month(o.order_date)');
```

Thanks [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) for the help!

Comment: Thanks, date_format(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') will give todays date. so what i need to pass instead '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: @Phil Oops! You're spot on. Thanks for the heads up. Mind checking it now?

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks to Phil I fixed my answer and this solution should work now. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @mmmshuddup also i missed to use 'group by', so how can i use month function here in zend?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that _that_ was part of your question. I edited my answer. Please check once more.